# table.setVisible(true) does not display my table

Tags: swing, user-interface, netbeans, jdbc

I don't know why but the table doesnot display. Values are being added into base table in mysql but it doesnot display in jtable.

```
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "insert into customers "+
        "values("+id+", \""+name+"\", "+"\""+add+"\", "+pno+");";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from customers;");
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
    JTable table = new JTable(model); 
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    model.addColumn("CustID"); 
    model.addColumn("CustName"); 
    model.addColumn("CustAdd"); 
    model.addColumn("PhoneNo"); 
    while(rs.next()){ 
        int tid = rs.getInt("custid");
        String tname = rs.getString("custname");
        String tadd = rs.getString("custadd");
        long tpno = rs.getLong("phoneno");
        model.addRow(new Object[]{tid, tname, tadd, tpno});
    }
    table.setVisible(true);
    }catch(SQLException se){
    jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(this, se);
}catch(Exception e){
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the `JTable` to the `JScrollPane`, but it does not look like you are adding the `JScrollPane` to anything.  (Unless there is code that we are not seeing.)

Comment: i did drag-and-drop it into the form. Won't it work?

Comment: Are you using a GUI builder of some sort?

Comment: I am not sure what code netbeans is adding to yours in order to support it's GUI building functionality, but the code fragment above definitely creates a `JScrollPane`, adds a `JTable` to it, and then both go out of scope (with the closing of the try/catch) without either of them being added to a container.  Maybe the `JScrollPane` needs to be a member variable in order for the GUI builder to do it's thing?  What you really have is a NetBeans question.